# Python how to sort a tuple (string, int) in numerical order for leaderboard

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, tuples

I'm fairly new to python.

So I have two files, my main python file (dice game) and an external txt file which stores player names and scores in tuples (int, string)

I need to sort the tuples numerically (highest first) and print only the top 5 to the main program.

How could I do this?

main python file:

```
    if p1_points > p2_points:
      winner_points = p1_points
      winner_player = p1_correct_login[0]
      winner = (winner_points, winner_player) # creates a tuple (2 sets of data in a single variable)

    elif p2_points > p1_points:
      winner_points = p2_points
      winner_player = p2_correct_login[0]
      winner = (winner_points, winner_player) # creates a tuple (2 sets of data in a single variable)

    print("Well done", winner_player, "you won with", winner_points, "points!") # winner variables 
    are determined by player scores.

    #------------------Store scores in winner txt file------------------
    winner = (winner_points, winner_player)
    file = open('winner.txt', 'a')
    file.write(''.join(str(winner)))
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()

    #----------------------Load, update and sort leaderboard-------------
    file = open("winner.txt", "r")
    leaderboard = [] # Should I pass tuples into a list?
```

winner.txt file:

```
    (75, 'leroy')
    (50, 'lex')
    (66, 'lex')
    (57, 'lex')
    (73, 'lex')
    (69, 'leroy')
    (71, 'leroy') 
    (76, 'leroy')
    (62, 'leroy')
    (64, 'lex')
    (67, 'lex')
    (60, 'lex')
```

Comment: `sorted(yourtuples, reverse=True)[:5]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me, I would try to use a dictionary to do it.

```
players = {
   75: 'leroy'
   50: 'lex
   66: 'lex'
   57: 'lex'
   73: 'lex'
   69: 'leroy'
   71: 'leroy'
   76: 'leroy'
   62: 'leroy'
   64: 'lex'
   67: 'lex'
   60: 'lex'
}
```

And you can sort it by using

```
winner_points.sort()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this looks interesting I will try this!